# Attempting to add two digits and print to VDU (total under 100)

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I'm attempting to add two digits and print the result to the VDU, the max number being returned will not exceed 3 digits.

So far I've been able to add a double digit number to my VDU, but I'm unsure as to how I would go about replicating this again AND adding the numbers together.

The code I've put together so far is:

```
In 00
sub al, 30
mul al, 0a
push al

in 00
sub al, 30
pop bl
add al, bl

push al
mod al, 0a
add al, 30
mov [c1], al

pop al
div al, 0a
add al, 30
mov [c0], al
end
```

Comment: This is not 8086, 8086 can't push 8 bit `al`. The code you have put so far is indeed some code, which something does. If you will put more code into the machine, it will execute more code. Maybe it will even do something interesting. If you did want each part to do something of particular interest, maybe add comments what is supposed to happen where, so other people can tell if you are right or not. Maybe even you will be able to recognize whether it works as expected and if not, what has to be different.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using lots of instructions that simply are not valid 8086 or x86 code!

```
in 00          Use a DOS function to get a character
mul al, 0a     Move the number 10 to an extra register
push al        Push a complete word to to stack
pop bl         Pop a complete word off the stack
mod al, 0a     Use the remainder you get from a division
div al, 0a     Move the number 10 to an extra register
```

This is what it could look like (no optimizations applied):

```
mov ah, 01h    Input a character for the tens
int 21h
sub al, 30h    Turn into number
mov bl, 10
mul al, bl     Multiplies AL by BL : So times 10
push ax

mov ah, 01h    Input a character for the units
int 21h
sub al, 30h    Turn into number
mov ah, 0      Clear AH so addition works correctly
pop bx
add ax, bx     Add tens and units


Here anything else!

mov bl, 10
div bl         Divides AX by BL : Gives remainder in AH, quotient in AL

add ah, 30h    Turn into character
mov [c1], ah

add al, 30h    Turn into character
mov [c0], al
```